# Give explicitly a real random variable X that generates $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$.

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

Let $\Omega = \{a,b,c,d\}$ have just four points with $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}= 2^{\Omega}$ and probability assignment $P[A] = \sum_{i=1}^{4} \frac{1}{10} \textbf{1}_{A}(\omega_{i})$ to events $A\in\mathcal{F}$ where, $\omega_{1}=a,\omega_{2}=b,\omega_{3}=c,\omega_{4}=d$. Define a collection of sets by
$$\mathcal{G} = \{\phi,\{a\},\{b,c\},\{d\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,d\},\{b,c,d\},\Omega\}$$

a) Give explicitly a real random variable X that generates $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$.

My approach - Since, $\sigma-$algebra represents information, knowing the value of $X(\omega)$ should tell us something about $\omega$ or which $\omega$ was chosen.

Since, $\{a,b,c\}$ are together, $X(a)=X(b)=X(c)$, and $\{b,c,d\}$ are together, $X(b)=X(c)=X(d)$. So, $X(\omega)$ has to be the same value i.e. $X(a)=X(b)=X(c)=X(d) = 10$ is one example of $X$.

Is this the correct way to think about this?

b) Give explicitly a real random variable Y that takes only two distinct values, for which $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X,Y)$.

$$Y(a)= $$ $$Y(b) = $$ $$Y(c) = $$ $$Y(d) = $$

How do I go about this?

Comment: Your example for a) is wrong. Think about it: If $X$ is a constant random variable, then how does $\sigma(X)$ look like?

Comment: Then $\sigma(X)$ will just be $\{\Omega,\phi\}$.

Comment: I get it. So, since $\{a\},\{b,c\},\{d\}$ can generate the entire $\sigma$-algebra, $we only look at those sets.

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for a) is not correct. A constant random variable generates the trivial sigma algebra consisting of only the empty set and the whole space.

What you need is a random variable with $X(b)=X(c)$ and $X(a), X(b),X(d)$ are all distinct.  So $X(a)=0, X(b)=X(c)=1$ and $X(d)=2$ will serve the purpose.

For b) just take any $Y$ such that $Y(b) \neq Y(c)$.

Comment: Because if $Y(b) = Y(c)$, then Y will generate the same $\sigma-$algebra as $X$? In that case, $\sigma (X,Y)$ will just be $\mathcal{G}$ and not $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @aa777 Yes, that is right.